# Rotate right using bit operation in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to come up with a function `int rotateRight (int x, int n)` that rotates `x` to the right by `n`. For example,

```
rotateRight(0x87654321,4) = 0x76543218
```

This is what I have so far:

```
int rotateRight(int x, int n) {
  int mask = (((1 << n)-1)<<(32-n));
  int reserve = (int)((unsigned) (x&mask) >>(32-n));
  return (x << n) | reserve; 
}
```

However, I am forbidden to use any casting, and the allowed operations are `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` and `>>`. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Forbidden to use something usually implies a homework question.  Were you given examples of something similar (like rotate the other direction)?

Comment: Looks like rotate left. :)

Comment: Is this what u mean ex. rotateRight(0x87654321,4) = 0x76543218 and rotateRight(0x87654321,8) = 0x65432187? I figured out how to perform such task but i dont know how to do it without casting.

Comment: "I am forbidden to use any casting" – but why would you need any sort of casting for this at all? Just make the arguments and temporaries `unsigned` and you're good to go.

Comment: Detail about `%32` - should code attempt that to fix things: `some_int%32` is not a [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) that returns 0-31.  It is the C remainder operand  that return -31 to 31 in this case. `some_int%32u` will achieve a "safe" reduction for all `int` encodings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically all you have to do is:

- shift everything right by n bits using right shift: `>>`
- shift the bits you want to rotate all the way to the left: `<<`
- Combine the shifted right and shifted left bits with `or`: `|`

See this code for an example implementation using the function signature you require:

```
int rotateRight(int x, int n) {

    //if n=4, x=0x12345678:

    //shifted = 0x12345678 >> 4 = 0x01234567
    int shifted = x >> n;

    //rot_bits = (0x12345678 << 28) = 0x80000000
    int rot_bits = x << (32-n);

    //combined = 0x80000000 | 0x01234567 = 0x81234567
    int combined = shifted | rot_bits;

    return combined;
}
```

This implementation isn't safe though, at least not without a few guarantees - namely that `x` will always be positive, and `n` will be positive and always `<= 32`.

If you pass in a negative integer for shifting, it will work incorrectly since it will sign-extend the left-most bit. If you want this function to work for all integers, you should change all the types from `int` to `unsigned int` (that way no sign-extension or negative left-shifting will take place) and then modulo `n` by 32 (`% 32`). Here is a safe version of the function:

```
unsigned int rotateRight(unsigned int x, unsigned int n) {

    //needed so you don't right shift more than int width
    n %= 32;

    //needed so you don't left shift more than int width
    unsigned int leftshift_val = (32-n) % 32 

    unsigned int shifted = x >> n;
    unsigned int rot_bits = x << leftshift_val;
    unsigned int combined = shifted | rot_bits;

    return combined;
}
```

And golfed down to a single line, for you minimalists:

```
unsigned rotr(unsigned x, unsigned n) {
    return (x >> n % 32) | (x << (32-n) % 32);
}
```

Comment: Can you please change your code to use `n &= 31;`, `unsigned x` and `unsigned shifted, rot_bits, combined;`? At present both answers to this code are dangerously wrong (esp. with that signed right-shift) and that's holding me back from upvoting.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist OP asked for a function with the signature `int (int, int)` so that's what I provided. I mention the dangers associated with the code underneath the code itself as well as how to fix it, but I will append a safe version of the code to the end of my answer.

Comment: `x << (32-n)` fails when `n==0`.  Shifting the bit width or more is undefined.  Could use `x << ((32-n)%32)` although that looks ugly.

Comment: Touché; But it is still possible to have the external interface specified by the OP, provided that there are internal assignments _(apparently, casts are forbidden)_ to `unsigned`. Something a la `int ror(int x, unsigned n){n&=31;unsigned ux = x;return n ? (ux >> n)|(ux << (32-n)) : ux;}`.

Comment: Sign extension of the MSB on right-shift isn't the only caveat in the `int` version of this. If `x << (32-n)` shifts a bit in to, or beyond the MSB of the signed type, the resulting expression is UB, well-before it is handed off to the final `|` operator. (§6.5.7/4).

Comment: @chux Fair point, I added that extra precaution and then golfed it down.

Comment: `//needed so you don't right shift more than int width///needed so you don't left shift more than int width`: that is good info! I was getting hung up on that silly detail when it is just a safety measure to ensure a proper input domain! Probably needs an `if(n>0)` around your modulo operations to handle `n==0` as @chux mentioned, and an `if(n==0) {combined = x};`.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Note that the size of the integer depends on the compiler. Instead of a hardcoded modulo 32, you should check `sizeof(int)` on your compiler

Answer (score 1):

A rotation is done with a combination of left and right shifts.

Shifting a signed integer's sign bit is a problem.  Suggest converting to `unsigned` to perform the shift. [@The Paramagnetic Croissant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477950/the-paramagnetic-croissant)

> An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right.

Shifting by the bit width or more is a problem.  Limit actual shifting to `n modulo Bit_width`.  OP's `(...<<(32-n));` code is a problem when `n == 0`.

OP's example looks more like a left rotate.  Will assume the function should rotate right.  `(0x87654321,4)` --> `0x18765432`.  [@Mark Shevchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051621/mark-shevchenko)

An `int` may have a width other than 32.

---

```
#include <limits.h>
#define INT_BIT_WIDTH (sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT)

int rotateRight(int x, int n) {
  unsigned xu = x;
  unsigned nu = n;
  nu %= INT_BIT_WIDTH;
  unsigned y = xu >> nu;
  if (nu > 0) {
    y |= xu << (INT_BIT_WIDTH - nu);
  }
  return y;
}
```

---

[Edit] as OP is limited to `~ & ^ | + << >>`, use the alternate following code.
Note: This is an issue in rare cases where the width of an `int` is not a power of 2.

```
// nu %= INT_BIT_WIDTH;
nu &= INT_BIT_WIDTH - 1;
```

[Edit2]  Thought I would form an `unsigned` minimalistic solution as inspired by @RPGillespie as OP cannot use `%`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#define UNS_WIDTH    (sizeof (unsigned) * CHAR_BIT)
#define UNS_WIDTH_M1 (UNS_WIDTH - 1)

unsigned unsigned_rotate_right(unsigned x, unsigned n) {
  return (x >> (n & UNS_WIDTH_M1)) | (x << ((UNS_WIDTH - n) & UNS_WIDTH_M1));
}
```

Comment: I notice OP cannot use `-` either, so under the light assumption that we're using a 2's complement machine, replace `- n` with `+ (~n+1)`. I don't object to the other minuses since they are compile-time evaluable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this explanation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-bits-of-an-integer/), rotation can be done with the following implementation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define INT_BITS 32

/*Function to left rotate n by d bits*/
int leftRotate(int n, unsigned int d)
{
   /* In n<<d, last d bits are 0. To put first 3 bits of n at
     last, do bitwise or of n<<d with n >>(INT_BITS - d) */
   return (n << d)|(n >> (INT_BITS - d));
}
```

Comment: it should be `unsigned int n`, otherwise an overflowing leftshift will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch That's not even the biggest problem! That's almost an _academic_ concern compared to the fact that **right**-shifting `n` **will** sign-extend `n` if it's negative on 2's complement machines (which is to say, the vast majority of them)!